# What to search when looking for the index of a span element within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to retrieve the index of a specific  object within an HTML collection of children converted into an array.

The array is made of all DOM elements that were surrounded by span tags within a certain range.

My plan is to use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method on the array, however I'm not sure whic parameter search element to use within the method.

Below is my initial code.

```
var htmlCollectionChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(range.commonAncestorContainer.children);
console.log(htmlCollectionChildren.indexOf(xxx)
```

below is an example representation of the array. Each span is an object, with plenty of parameters.

```
[span#1.highlight, span#0.highlight]

0:span#1.highlight

1:span#0.highlight
```

I tried to pass the string `span#0.highlight` as a parameter, however it returns -1.

```
(htmlCollectionChildren.indexOf('span#1.highlight')
```

What should I search for?

Comment: are you looking for elements with a certain class name in it? - If so, you can use the `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` method

Comment: No, i'm trying to guess the position of the span within all the spans existing in the paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.filter()` by the concatenated values of `tagName`, as lower case characters, `"#"`, `id`, `"."` and `className`

```
let match = "span#0.highlight";

let res = htmlCollectionChildren.filter(({id, className, tagName}) => 
            `${tagName.toLowerCase()}#${id}.${className}` === match);
```

Comment: Thank you - forgive me if i got it wrong, but this only returns the object. what  I would be looking for is the index of the object within the array.

Comment: @Peterdev You can substitute `.findIndex()` for `.filter()`